# How can I add a character count / column ruler to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rulers

[image]

All, I have been searching for a ruler similar to this for **VS Code**. I do not see an extension, and I am honestly not 100% on what this ruler is actually known as. It is **used to quickly determine the number of characters in a line**. I know that there is a read-out on the information panel that will display how many characters one has highlighted, but **I like the ruler a lot** better.  **Does anyone have an actual name for this device? Is anyone aware of an existing extension similar to this?**

Answer (score 1):

This was requested in [Show column numbers in vscode #60537](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60537). It was closed as "out-of-scope" with the following message (emphasis added):

> We closed this issue because we don't plan to address it in the foreseeable future. You can find more detailed information about our decision-making process [here](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope). **If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider**.

Please be respectful and productive if you make comments there to explain why you'd like to see this feature implemented.

I'm pretty sure an extension couldn't add such a feature except maybe by doing some crazy wizardry with actual text in the editor buffer and something like the sticky line feature.

Comment: I understand. I am disappointed but will be okay. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this